# Only initializers, entity members(...). Unable to do a Where() on a specific column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

I'm getting this error when trying to execute ".Where()" on this line (status is of type byte):

```
selectedUsers = entities.Users.Where(n => n.Status == status).ToList();
```

While this works totally fine:

```
var user = entities.Users.Where(n => n.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is my user class:

```
class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
}
```

And my table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users2](
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[UserDisplayName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Status] [tinyint] NULL)
```

Detailed Error Message:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The specified type member 'Status' is not
>   supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are supported.

OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```

Any ideas? I can assign the entities.Users.ToList() to a variable and do a where on it (which works), but I'd like to avoid pulling all the data back.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please tell us the full text of the error.  We cannot figure it out based on your post's subject line.

Comment: You're right, sorry for that. Updated.

Comment: Have you shown us the complete entity class here, complete with attributes? How about anything in the `OnModelCreating` function in your context?

Comment: Does your database include any null values in the status column?

Comment: There are no nulls in the Status column. I didn't alter the OnModelCreating method so it's just throwing the UnintentionalCodeFirstException exception. I've added it to the question.

Comment: What type is the status variable you are using for comparison?

Comment: It's byte. Same as Status in the User class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnModelCreating` function body lets me think that you use a designer-based approach, i.e you have an `.edmx` file that shows you your model, since that code is [automatically generated by T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.unintentionalcodefirstexception(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_6).

I wonder, then, if Entity Framework knows that the `Status` property of your `User` class needs to be mapped with the `Status` column of your `Users2` table. Opening the `.edmx` and inspecting the `User` entity should tell you that.

If it's not there, you might be able to add the mapping yourself.

Comment: Thank's, that helped!

Comment: I'm happy it did. If you have more details about how you solved your issue, could you add a comment to help people potentially stumbling on the question?